# Please suggest reg express for every nth occurrence of a character in a string in vba

Tags: vba, expression

At the very outset, let me confess. I am not a developer nor do I have any technical background. However, I have learned a bit of coding. I want to a regular expression for finding every nth position of a character. For example, google, yahoo, rediff, facebook, cnn, pinterest, gmail. I want to find every third occurrence of the comma in the string and replace it with a semicolon. This is for a excel vba macro I am working on. For now, I am trying to loop through it and then replace. If the data is large, the macro fails. Would appreciate your reply. Thanks a ton in advance.

Here is what I am doing:

```
Option Explicit
```

Sub reg()

```
Dim regx As RegExp
Set regx = New RegExp
Dim allMatches As Object

Dim contents As String
Dim contents2 As String
contents = "hello, wow, true, false, why, try, cry, haha"
contents = "contents1" & contents
regx.pattern = ",{4}"
regx.Global = True
regx.IgnoreCase = False
Set allMatches = regx.Execute(contents)

contents2 = regx.Replace(contents, ";")


MsgBox contents2
```

End Sub

I get the data from all selected cells. Join it. Add semicolon (an indicator for the row end) at every fourth comma found. Please suggest if there is a better way to do it as I am new to this:

Here is what I have done currently by looping through array. I want to avoid this.

```
Function insertColon(sInputString As String) As Variant


Dim data3 As String
Dim sFind As String
Dim sReplacewith As String
Dim result As String
'Dim i As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer

sFind = ","
sReplacewith = ";"
data3 = sInputString
```

' MsgBox = data3
'    Dim J As Integer
    Application.Volatile
    FindN = 0
    'Dim i As Integer
'    i = 1

```
Counter = 4
```

'    MsgBox Len(data3)

```
While InStr(Counter, sInputString, sFind)

    FindN = InStr(Counter, sInputString, sFind)

    data3 = Application.Substitute(data3, sFind, sReplacewith, Counter)

    Counter = Counter + 3
```

'        MsgBox "loop" & i
'
'        i = i + 1

```
Wend
```

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused. You say "I want to find every third occurrence of the comma in the string". Does that mean that every 3th occurrence might not be a comma? Or you want to replace every 3th occurrence in the text with a comma?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you properly then all your code could be summarized to a few lines

```
        Dim sText As String
        sText = "hello, wow, true, false, why, try, cry, haha, huh, muh"

        For p = 3 To Len(sText) Step 2
          sText = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(sText, ",", ";", p)
        Next p

       MsgBox sText
       'Output
       'hello, wow, true; false, why, try; cry, haha, huh; muh
```

Test it and let me know whether it fails. If not don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for replying. Is there a way to use regular expression to get this job done. Just asking.

Comment: Well, the problem is that you need every 3th occurrence to be replaced and not all occurrences. If you need to replace all occurrences then the code will be summarized to just one line of code using regular expression. I am wondering whether the proposed solution worked for you? Did the macro fail?

Comment: I tried editing my comment yesterday. True, your code is a shortened version of mine. Thanks for that. Yes, the code works when I declare P as an integer explicitly. My problem is not solved. I want to avoid the looping part or minimize the loop because of the string is too large, there is every chance the macro will stop working...so I thought reg expression is the way to go...Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Reg expressions are usually quite heavy and not necessarily better solution than a for loop. The fact that you will write fewer lines of code doing the same thing does not always mean it will run faster. The macro should not stop working since the for loop is definitely better than almost all reg. expressions. It some cases it may take longer but eventually it will finish

Comment: I stand corrected. I have to learn a lot still. Thanks user3793865